# building a boolean array from many text files using python

Tags: python, arrays, string, text, boolean

I have a number of text files that list (among other things) a persons characteristics 1 person per file. The person files comes in a tab delimited format eg person_1.txt may be:

```
 xyz     tall     123
 abc     happy     123
 aby     slim     456
 zyg     intelligent     345
 mno     brown hair     678
```

person_2.txt may be:

```
 xyz     average height     012
 abc     happy     123
 ccc     slightly overweight     123
 def     bubbly     234
 cde     brown hair     567
```

etc, I have another .txt file called characteristics that holds all the possible characteristics (about 600) that the people files have. They are listed 1 per line such as follows:

```
 brown hair
 slightly overweight
 bubbly
 tall
 happy
 etc
```

I also have one more file that contains the names of all the 'people files' 1 per line eg:

```
 person_1.txt
 person_2.txt
 person_3.txt
 etc
```

I am looking for a script that will output a boolean array telling me which people have which characteristics, either comma or tab separated. Something like the one shown below:

```
 characteristic     tall     happy     bubbly     slightly overweight   etc
 person_1     true     true     false     false
 person_2     false     true     true     true  
 etc
```

I am quite new to programming and have never had any formal tuition so any pointers would be great. Many thanks!

Ok, so I've made some progress:

```
 #make a list of characteristics
 f = open('geneList.txt')
 geneList = [line.strip() for line in open('geneList.txt')]
 geneList = sorted(geneList)
 f.close()

 i=0

 #add a tab space to make room for the names in subsequent lines
 with open('output.txt', 'a') as firstTab:
         firstTab.write('\t',)

 #add the first line to the matrix - a line with all genes tab delimited
 while i < len(geneList):
     with open('output.txt', 'a') as firstLine:
            firstLine.write(geneList[i] + '\t',)
            i=i+1

 with open('output.txt', 'a') as newLine:
         newLine.write('\n',)

 #make a list of all the people files
 p = open('people.txt')
 peopleList = [line.strip() for line in open('people.txt')]
 peopleList = sorted(peopleList)
 p.close()
```

Method to compare the genes in a persons file to the geneList and return a boolean for each gene in the geneList (I'm struggling with getting a list of files to have each line read individually, I've tried:

```
 with (peopleList[0], 'r') as f:
      f.readline()
```

I'm wondering if my syntax is incorrect as this statement gives an error or if there is a better way? I need to search through the geneList and if there is no matching gene in the persons list of genes/characteristics then add a 'False' to another list. If it is present then add a 'True' to the list then append the list below on one line. I would try something like:

```
 genePresent.append( 'GeneA': True, 'GeneB':False etc)
```

Method to write the people as the first variable then a boolean output for each gene (not yet finished). I plan to make a list of 'True/False' strings that can be appended on the same line after each person and under the corresponding characteristic/gene

```
 n=0
 while n < len(peopleList):
     with open('output.txt', 'a') as outf:
         outf.write(peopleList[n] + '\t' + 'genePresent' + '\n')
         n=n+1
```

Unfortunately they don't teach any coding on biology courses so I apologize if I am asking really basic questions

Comment: You'll probably like to look at Python manual, in particular file IO operations: `with open("someFile.txt","r") as f:`, `read` and `readlines`. Think about the algorithm, i.e. the steps you need to take in order to go fro where you start to where you want to end up. Write them down or make a block diagram of those steps ad then write it up in computer code, block by block.  **on SO note** formally to post here you should at least attempt the problem yourself to get help.

Comment: Seems like a `freeloader question` to me. 
It would be nice if you put in some code that you have already written  and ask us where you are getting stuck rather than asking for a script that does this for you.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Aleksander Lidtke, its difficult knowing where to start when your as new as I am to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can help you **plan**, but no one is going to solve it for you (I hope):

What you are facing requires very light experience with [data structures](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html), [file IO](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) and [string manipulation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/strings.html).

You should use these methods (or similar ones), and route the program flow accordingly:

```
# you should probably store person records in a data structure
persons = []

def read_persons_config_file(filename):
    # this method will read the line separated person records from the persons file
    # it will use methods like [open][4] to access the file and [readlines][5] to use data
    # it should probably call read_person_file() on each record
    # this method can maintain a list of persons
    pass

def read_person_file(filename):
    # this method should read a single person record and store it in a [data structure][6]
    # of your choice. I'd recommend you go with [dictionaries][7], but there are many
    # alternatives
    # this method should either return a result to the caller (the data structure you chose)
    # or append the data structure to a list of data structures (persons) you've created
    pass
```

Once you have both methods in place, you can go on and use the data you've structured.

Listing it after filtering\modification is as simple as using [google](https://www.google.co.il/?gws_rd=cr&ei=oljIUr__K8aL4ATIg4GYDg)

Do try and use google **before** asking a question, for people to do the work for you you can use [this](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=freelancers) link.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I've made some progress and have come up with this: